# Создание GUI на Python

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Как я могу реализовать? Опыта реализации *GUI* нет от слова совсем, не представляю каким инструментом пользоваться, подскажите.

Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры в полях `Enter Param 1/2` числовые значения параметров. 
Кнопка `Save` сохраняет эти параметры на жёсткий диск в **.txt** файл, кнопка `load` выгружает параметры с жесткого диска в форму. 
Код предоставить не могу, т.к. ещё пока не знаю как реализовать.

[image: Как я могу реализовать данную с наименьшими времязатратами? Опыта реализации GUI нет от слова совсем, не представляю каким инструментом пользоваться, подскажите.]

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну Роман написал, я нарисовал. Изучайте.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(627, 346)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lineEdit_param1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_param1.setObjectName("lineEdit_param1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_param1, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_param2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_param2.setObjectName("lineEdit_param2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_param2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_save.setObjectName("pushButton_save")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_save, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_load = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_load.setObjectName("pushButton_load")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_load, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_param1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_param1.setObjectName("label_param1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_param1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_param2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_param2.setObjectName("label_param2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_param2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 627, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit_param1.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Param 1"))
        self.lineEdit_param2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Param 2"))
        self.pushButton_save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_load.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))
        self.label_param1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Param1"))
        self.label_param2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Param2"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.pushButton_save.clicked.connect(self.save_params)
        self.pushButton_load.clicked.connect(self.load_params)

    def save_params(self):
        with open('params.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(f'{self.lineEdit_param1.text()}\n')
            f.write(f'{self.lineEdit_param2.text()}\n')

        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Save', 'Параметры сохранены.')    
        self.lineEdit_param1.clear()
        self.lineEdit_param2.clear()

    def load_params(self):
        file, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './', 'Files (*.txt)')
        if file:
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                self.lineEdit_param1.setText(f.readline())
                self.lineEdit_param2.setText(f.readline())

            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Load', 'Параметры загружены.')        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 15, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**param_1_2.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>627</width>
    <height>346</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="2">
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_param1">
      <property name="placeholderText">
       <string>Enter Param 1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_param2">
      <property name="placeholderText">
       <string>Enter Param 2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_save">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Save</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_load">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Load</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_param1">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Param1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_param2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Param2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>627</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Сперва скачайте QtDesigner и нарисуйте там нужную форму и сохраните.
Потом поищите как заставить форму выводится.
Enter Param это textEdit, чтобы получить текст с textEdit, можно использовать метод text() `text = self.textEdit.text()`.Чтобы заставить кнопки работать можно использовать `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(имя функции)`, так мы подключим функцию к кнопке, а в функции уже будем , или читать или записывать информацию.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!